# Insert multiline in varchar

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, multiline, varchar

Is it possible to save a multiline varchar in SQL Server?

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(256)
SELECT @SQL = 'SELECT
                  ID, Name
                FROM
                  Cust'
INSERT INTO
   MultiLineTBL (SQL)
VALUES
   (@SQL)
```

So this query:

```
SELECT SQL From MultiLineTBL
```

will return:

```
SELECT 
   ID, Name
FROM
   Cust
```

Not the straight line:

```
SELECT ID, NAME FROM Cust
```

How is it possible to store a multiline varchar?

Comment: It's multiline. Try PRINT @SQL; Management Studio datagrid can't show miltiline string

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible to store a multi-line `varchar` in a table. In fact, the value in your example *is* stored correctly.

As [AlexK has correctly commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26095867/insert-multiline-in-varchar#comment40895098_26095867), multi-line values are not displayed correctly in SQL Server Management Studio when it is configured to return the results in a grid, and that (viewing the results in a grid) must be what gave you the wrong impression. As per my observation, SSMS replaces every control character, including CR (`CHAR(13)`) and LF (`CHAR(10)`), with a space in this display mode.

Try switching to `Results to Text` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) before running the query and you will see that line delimiters are actually preserved.

Answer (score 1):

Your sql query have syntex error:

```
 DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(256) ;
   --please update query like that
    set @SQL = 'insert into MultiLineTBL(col1,col2) 
                   SELECT ID, Name FROM Cust';

    --and  execure like that:
    exec(@SQL);
```